# How to make HTML/Javascript Countdown with Message at End

Tags: javascript, html, countdown

I am very new to coding, so please excuse my ignorance. I'm trying to get a countdown that displays the message "AND THE VOTES ARE IN!" when the timer reaches zero. I then want the link https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=26WpGvLpFzw to be displayed 5 seconds after the countdown is over (the message "AND THE VOTES ARE IN!" will be displayed for 5 seconds, then the link will be shown). I currently have the code for the countdown, but not for the messages to be displayed after the countdown is over. My code so far is:

```
<p> Voting period: <span id="countdowntimer">10 </span> Seconds</p>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var timeleft = 10;
    var downloadTimer = setInterval(function(){
    timeleft--;
    document.getElementById("countdowntimer").textContent = timeleft;
    if(timeleft <= 0)
        clearInterval(downloadTimer);
    },1000);
</script>
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `setTimeout`, its somewhat similar to `setInterval` but delays and runs the code inside after a set amount of milliseconds.

```html
<p id="foo"> Voting period: <span id="countdowntimer">10 </span> Seconds</p>

<script type="text/javascript">
  var timeleft = 10;

  //added this next 4 lines for the link
  var a = document.createElement('a');
  var link = document.createTextNode("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=26WpGvLpFzw");
  a.appendChild(link);
  a.href = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=26WpGvLpFzw";

  var downloadTimer = setInterval(function() {
    timeleft--;
    document.getElementById("countdowntimer").textContent = timeleft;
    if (timeleft <= 0) {
      clearInterval(downloadTimer);

      document.getElementById("foo").innerHTML = "AND THE VOTES ARE IN!";
      //added this part for the delay
      setTimeout(function() {
        document.getElementById("foo").innerHTML = "";
        document.getElementById("foo").appendChild(a);
      }, 5000);


    }
  }, 1000);
</script>
```

Comment: I appreciate the help Mack! It definitely works.